# Get date of a day in last week of a month using powershell

Tags: powershell

How to retrieve the date of the last Wednesday in the last week of month using powershell?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? [So] is not a code-writing service; you need to provide information describing a specific problem, ideally including a [mcve]. Please see [ask] a Good Question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [so] is not a code-writing service - please see my other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to get the date of, e.g. the last Wednesday of the current month could be

```
# Day to match
$day = "Wednesday"   

# First, fetch the last day's date of the current month. 
# I.e. add one month to the current date and remove today's date from the date.
# 3.4.2018 + 1 month - 3 days = 30.4.2018
$lastDay = (Get-Date).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-$(Get-Date).AddMonths(1).Day)

# Next remove one weeks worth of days, one day at a time, 
# from $lastDay until the DayOfWeek is equals to Wednesday
# Finally, do something, e.g. write the date to the console.
1..7 | %{ if($lastDay.AddDays(-$_).DayOfWeek -eq $day) { `
    Write-Host $lastDay.AddDays(-$_) `
}}
```